# Fragment's layout blinks after launching activity and calling finish() on the old activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm calling finish() on a fragment's activity after launching a new activity. the problem is, when finishing the old activity, the layout and its finishing's animation shows up when the method is called.

I've tried to make the finish first, but it was horrible as i was able to see it.

Code:

```
    if(getActivity() != null){
        Glide.with(getActivity()).load(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(mIcon);
        Animation myFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.anim_splash_icon_pulse_scale);
        mIcon.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);

        int mRandom = new Random().nextInt(mMemesArray.length);
        mMemeText.setText(mMemesArray[mRandom]);

        try{
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityMain.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    getActivity().startActivity(intent);

                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            getActivity().finish();
                        }
                    },1000 * 2);
                }
            },1000 * 3);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I've tried to remove the views, cancel the animated ImageView. Had the same result.

Comment: I've already checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31817937/activity-layout-blinking-after-finish-is-called

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand this is caused by activity transition overlap. To overcome this issue I have used the following values in the onCreate() methods of both activities:

```
getWindow().setAllowEnterTransitionOverlap(false);
getWindow().setAllowReturnTransitionOverlap(false);
```

Comment: min-api in my project is 16, so this solution won't work. I have solved the issue by adding a fade animation in a bundle and attached it to the intent. the fade animation has a duration of 200 with an alpha of 1.0 for both alpha fields, thus the fade animation won't happen and the window won't overlap when finishing (tested and seems weird, but does the job).